# Can't Install Tor on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: 16.04, directory, ubuntu-gnome, tar, tor

I tried to install Tor Browser by the instruction l found on Tor's official website. But I couldn't install it because of the following error come.

**My Input**

```
tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux32-5.5.5_LANG.tar.xz
```

**Error Message**

```
tar (child): tor-browser-linux32-5.5.5_LANG.tar.xz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue seems to be that you are not in the same folder as the file `tor-browser-linux32-5.5.5_LANG.tar.xz`, so the file is not found, as you don't say where you downloaded the file, I can't tell you how to get to it but if it is in your /home/downloads run

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

then

```
tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux32-5.5.5_LANG.tar.xz
```

to extract it, and keep following your guide.

As you are struggling at this stage, building the source may not be the best way to install tor, it will get much more complex.

Instead just open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt install tor
```

to install from the repositories.

Comment: Is there only apt install for a reason or should it be apt-get install?

Comment: @NonStandardModel In 16.04 `apt` became the default package manager, for commands like `apt-get install` or `apt-get update`, you can just run `apt install` or `apt update`, `apt` will replace `apt-get` but `apt-get` will still work. Here is some more info https://www.maketecheasier.com/apt-vs-apt-get-ubuntu/